# Cross Platform Net.System.Sockets nuget error

Tags: android, sockets, frameworks, nuget, platform

When I try to add sockets nuget to my Project I got MonoAndroid 7.1 error. I tried to change Android version but it still giving MonoAndroid 7.1 error. I have an empty Project. I use Vs2017. How can I fix this?

Comment: post your code and error log

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. 
Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). 
**DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. 
Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).